# How to enable check strings = F in read.Alteryx WITHIN ALTERYX DESIGNER

Tags: r, alteryx

When I import a csv data frame into R I can do

```
read.csv("some.csv", check.names=F)
```

This will keep column names with spaces in them. For example the column name 
`some data column` will be read in as `some data column`.

The problem is when I use the R developer tool in Alteryx to read in a csv.

```
read.Alteryx("#1", mode="data.frame")
```

The column name `some data column` turns into `some.data.column.`

Now I realize I could use regular expressions and other parsing tools to rename the columns to what they were originally but I am hoping there is an alternative.

Comment: Not able to find `read.Alteryx` to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry read.Alteryx can only be used inside Alteryx Designer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like to following will work:

```
df1 = read.Alteryx("#1", mode="data.frame")
df1metadata <- read.AlteryxMetaInfo("#1")
colnames(df1) <- df1metadata$Name
```